# Why aren't churches registered more massively?

Tags: united-states, religion, tax-law

When reading an article in the [Huffington Post](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/start-your-own-church_n_55d24635e4b07addcb43bd60?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAGYogoAsSvxeYjwYXMLvr_Tm2dHe_eO7nOtRIIUxgrbztC2Vlyt0rM8tKmqOGjuW-_wFcS8JKSicr92Gr8Ik8zUtN3d7vjS_qtr-3PYdG4jH8o3gIm0EB45e5oPZOQiih4KNA688LTjrvQ3Q8brgjlCkWDJ6UFLA3gMUknrZ0mfn) about how easy it is to register a church (as [shown by John Oliver](https://youtu.be/7y1xJAVZxXg)) I was wondering why the practice is not more widespread.

The American IRS does not take a position on religions so a minimal effort to check the marks would easily allow for tax benefits. I would guess that the more money is on the table, the more "organized" the organization could be (I am not talking about the philosophical aspect but the formal one, that is having all the processes in place so that an audit comes clean)).

I am from Europe where the financing of churches is more around taxing the believers, rather than having the church exempted from paying taxes so the usefulness of having a church is smaller (this is visible through the small number of recent churches, and when these arise it is rather a matter of dogma)). It seems however than in the US it is different.

Comment: Are you asking why people don't create fake churches with the intent to evade taxes?

Comment: @RossRidge: yes, sorry if it was not clear from my question. One thing though: "legally evade" (= use the church solely as a financial construction because it is allowed and financially useful)

Comment: It wouldn't be legal, that's why.  When you register a fake church you'd be committing a crime because you were lying to the government.   When you failed to pay taxes on the profits you made and distributed for non-charitable purposes (eg. paid to yourself)  you'd be committing a crime.

Comment: @RossRidge: what is a "fake church"? Apparently there are documented processes you need to have in place and that's all.

Comment: Just because the IRS does't do much investigate whether the beliefs of a religious organization are "truly and sincerely held by those professing them" doesn't make it legal to lie to the IRS by claiming this to be true when its not.

Comment: @RossRidge: I do not understand. Where is the lie? I registered a church according to the documentation, I follow the processes in the documentation and requirements.

Comment: In the registration itself.

Comment: @RossRidge: honestly, I do not understand what you are trying to say. Which part of the registration would be a lie? Pastafarianism is a registered religion, you can hardly do better and still - a religion (not for tax exemption, though but for more noble causes)

Comment: @RossRidge -  His point may be that it impossible to know how deeply held someone's beliefs are.  It would be a crime carried out entirely in one's head. Kind of weird when you look at it that way.

Comment: I don't understand why you think making knowingly false claims about the nature of the organization you're registering isn't a lie.   The fact that the IRS accepts your registration without investigating whether your claims are true doesn't make it any less of a lie.

Comment: @RossRidge: well, in order to **register an entity called "church"**, you need to formally do A, B and C (the points mentioned for instance in the article I linked to). Once you've done that you can apply for tax exemptions. Where is the lie?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite: not only that, but also the fact that the beliefs can be of all sorts. Again to take the example of Pastafarianism the beliefs are not binding (basically, you can believe or not in what is documented, that's your choice - it is just a suggestion). I am taking the example of Pastafarianism but others such as the Satanic Temple are similar.

Comment: You must believe the organization your registering is a religious organization.  If no one truly believes in your religion, including yourself, then you can't believe its a religious organization. The things the IRS says that religious organization must have in some combination aren't sufficient to make your organization a religious one in the absence of no one believing in the religion.

Comment: @RossRidge: what is a "religious organization"? Pastafarians are? Satanic Temple? A"religious organization" is defined legally as an entity that follows some legally defined points, that's all. There is nothing more in the law that these points one must follow (logistic points, nothing spiritual)

Comment: @WoJ No, it's not legally defined like that.

Comment: @RossRidge: so how is it defined? Is there a place in the US law where it is stated that "you must believe in the church you are forming (and this is how we are going to check that)", or "your belief must make sense"? I profoundly doubt so, taken into account the churches I mentioned that are officially registered

Comment: The ordinary definition of religion applies. It may not be a well defined word, but if no one believes in a religion it's clearly not a religion.

Comment: @RossRidge: I am looking for a **legal** perspective, not a spiritual one - this is why I asked on SE Law. I did not see anything about believing (or believing in  "universally recognized" stuff) in the documents I read. I just saw a (legal and procedural) checklist.

Comment: When the law doesn't define a word, the legal definition is the ordinary one.

Comment: This document by the IRS may help you to understand the issue. https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/eotopica94.pdf  A church is a kind of tax exempt religious organization that is allowed a broader source of income by law, however the law doesn't define what a church is. The article notes that according to one court decision "in the absence of a statutory definition of 'church,' we should apply 'the common meaning and usage of the word.'" and that the "fourteen points test" you believe is definitive, is merely how IRS attempts to apply this definition.  It's not the the legal definition itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may well be the case that registering a phony church is easy and that there are no particular checks.  However, this by itself would gain you no tax benefits.

In order to actually reduce your personal taxes, you'd have to do something like funneling some part of your income into the church, and then having the church pay for expenses that you'd otherwise pay for by yourself (your house, your car, etc).  It's this last part that will get you busted for tax fraud.  Churches and other nonprofits are only allowed to spend their funds in ways that further their religious or charitable mission, with record-keeping and reporting requirements and the possibility of audits.  If the church's expenditures consist mainly of buying stuff for the founder, it'll be obvious to the IRS that this isn't a "real" church, and the founder will be taxed and/or prosecuted accordingly.

Comment: Or in other words... that sneaky loophole you just thought of? Its called fraud and is a crime.

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring the question of whether knowingly trying to deceive the IRS about the nature and purposes of an organization is a crime or even a lie, running any sort of tax-exempt organization for your own benefit is tax evasion and a crime.

What you propose actually does happen in the US, but it's non commonly done by claiming tax exempt status a religious organization. Instead of registering fake churches (which strictly speaking isn't necessary as user6726's answer says), it's simpler just to register a fake charity. You don't need any of those things that you've noted that the IRS says a religious organization must have.

Done intelligently, people running these scam charities do just enough charitable work to avoid investigation by the authorities while diverting the majority of earnings and donations of the organization to themselves through salaries and payments to for-profit businesses they own.

Done not-so-intelligently, virtually all the proceeds of the scam charity end up in the hands the people running it, and those people often get caught and end up in jail.  If proven, the [charges against Steve Bannon](https://www.cnn.com/2020/08/20/politics/bannon-build-the-wall-indictment/index.html) would be a notable recent example of this.  While it's less common with religious organizations, people have done time for misusing a religious organization's tax exempt status.  For example a [Virginia couple were sentenced to prison](https://newsadvance.com/news/local/woman-gets-18-months-for-role-in-irs-fraud-case/article_687428ec-53da-11e8-86f3-07fc5a02c998.html) for crimes relating to a scheme to route profits from a business through a religion organization they had set up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1) despite the fact that I truly do not understand the part about deceiving anyone. If my church states that the doctrine is, say, "to think" (just "think") and I do, then I do not see the problem (really, honestly). I am interested in the technical/legal aspects of why not having this financial construction more often (since it is legally allowed and provided)

Answer (score 3):

In the US, there is no required registering of churches and religion is an unregulated industry because of the First Amendment to the Constitution:

> "Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof".

Congress *does* have the power to levy taxes, and makes certain exceptions to the general rule requiring paying taxes on income, for organizations to have certain purposes – organizations that do certain things. This includes, but is not limited to, churches.

As long as you do those things that allow you to have this tax exemption, and don't do the things that prevent you from having that exemption, you can gain tax exempt status.

The "Free Exercise Clause" means that you can't do things that prevent churches from exercising their religion (this is a hugely controversial balancing act). The specifics of what you must/must not do for exemption under 501(c)(3) are explained [here](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p1828.pdf).

There are no "content" requirements so a so-called "church" could look nothing like a conventional church, it just has to follow the specific rules about what the organization does.